# Multiplicar dos input en R

Tags: r, rstudio, input

hoy empecé a jugar con RStudio y hay algo que no logré encontrar cómo hacerlo. La idea es sencilla: que el usuario inserte (con números flotantes) la altura (a) y el largo (b) de una habitación, que se multipliquen (a*b) para calcular el área, y luego que se muestre un mensaje con el resultado. Mi (inútil) intento fue algo así:

```
print("Hello")
a=double(readline("Width (meters): "))
b=double(readline("Lenght (meters): "))
area=a*b
print=("The area of your room is ",area, "meters.")
```

Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bienvenido al mundo R. Si vienes de otros lenguajes seguramente te irás encontrando con algunas cosas llamativas, pero al poco tiempo te acostumbras. Veamos los problemas que tienes con tu código:

```
a=double(readline("Width (meters): "))
```

La función `double()` crea un valor de este tipo pero a partir de un número no de una cadena, compara la ejecución de `double("1")` y `double(1)` para verificarlo. Y `readline()` retorna siempre una cadena. Lo correcto sería hacer una conversión explícita mediante `as.double()`

```
a <- as.double(readline("Width (meters): "))
```

**Aclaración**: el ingreso debe ser una cadena numérica valida, sino, recibirás un `Warning` y el resultado será un valor faltante `NA`. El otro problema que veo es:

```
print=("The area of your room is ",area, "meters.")
```

La sintaxis de esto por un lado es incorrecta y confunde al interprete de R, ¿es una asignación? ¿es una llamada a un `print`? si fuera la llamada a un `print()` lo correcto sería concatenar primero los valores mediante `paste()`

```
print(paste("The area of your room is ",area, "meters."))
```

finalmente:

```
print("Hello")
a <- as.double(readline("Width (meters): "))
b <- as.double(readline("Lenght (meters): "))
area <- a*b
print(paste("The area of your room is ",area, "meters."))
```

**Comentario final**: si trabajas con **RStudio** tienes que contemplar la forma en que por defecto se evalúan las sentencias. Si buscas ejecutar este código simplemente seleccionándolo y haciendo click en el botón `Run`, esto no funcionará como lo estarías esperando, ya que se evalúa de a linea independiente y no el script completo.  Para ejecutar el Script debes salvarlo y hacer click en el botón "Source". Recuerda también que la acción de input se traslada al panel de consola.

Answer (score 1):

Para combinar texto es necesario usar la función `paste()` porque `print()` requiere un solo valor. Además, para que puedas volver a usar el código, es necesario convertirlo en una función.

```r
read_area <- function(){

  print("Hello")  
  a <- as.double(readline("Width (meters): "))
  b <- as.double(readline("Lenght (meters): "))
  area <- as.character(a*b)
  paste("The area of your room is", area, "meters.")

}
```

Ahora puedes usar `read_area()` para pedir ambos inputs al usuario.